# Unable to get Azure Blob Container info using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I'm trying get Azure Blob Container information using powershell. I'm using below script.

I have tried changing the **Set-AzStorageContainerAcl** to **Blob** and **Container** Still no luck.

```html
    $StorageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount
    FOREACH ($StorageAccount in $StorageAccounts) {   
            $AllContainers = Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $StorageAccount.Context
            $AccountCapacity = 0

            FOREACH ($Container in $AllContainers) { 
            $ListOfBLobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $Container.Name -Context $StorageAccount.Context
            $length = 0
            $BlobCapacity = 0            
            $BlobCapacity = ($listOfBlobs | Measure-Object 'Length' -Sum).Sum

            $AccountCapacity = $AccountCapacity + $BlobCapacity   
            }
```

This works when I use my credentials. But when I try to use App Registration to connect to Subscription, I'm getting below error.

```html
Get-AzStorageContainerAcl : The client 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx' with object id 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listKeys/action' over scope 
'/subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/StorageAccountName' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
At line:11 char:30
+ ... ontainers = Get-AzStorageContainerAcl -Context $StorageAccount.Contex ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzStorageContainer], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.Cmdlet.GetAzureStorageContainerCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not given Application the right RBAC permissions to access storage account or subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#assign-the-application-to-a-role

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal

Comment: Hello @Hannel, I have tried giving all roles in subscription to my App Registration. Still same error. Unable to execute the command Get-AzStorageContainerAcl. 

Can you tell me what am i missing here. I even tried giving subscription owner role (which is against our policy) to the App Registration.  I also tried changing the Access policy of Blob container to Blob and Container level. still no luck

Comment: The script doesn't really work but with the right permissions you will not get the error you are getting.  https://i.imgur.com/mzl52BQ.png

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the access part. It was Set-AzStorageContainerAcl.

However, the script that I pasted in the above question is taking multiple hours just to go through a single Storage Account. I all I want is the data size used by a storage account.

So, the subscription has multiple Storage Accounts. Each Storage account has 100+ Containers in it. I need the consolidated final data used per Storage account which is sum of all container data.

```html
Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $Container.Name -Context $StorageAccount.Context
```

Get-AzStorageBlob which goes through all containers is taking for ever to finish.